# Listfiles() in android is not working

Tags: android

Im developing a Music player for which I need to retrieve all mp3 files from my storage. Im using getExternalStorageDirectory() function to obtain the external storage directory. But When I tried listfiles() on this path,its returning a null object. Im using a API Level 21 . And I have already gave
 uses-permission in android manifest
both for reading and writing external storages,Even after doing this Im getting a null object.

Code:

> File root= new
>   File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
>
> Log.v("file exists ", root.exists()+""); Log.v(" file is
>
> a directory",root.isDirectory()+""); Log.v("file can be
>   read",root.canRead()+""); Log.v("listfile value",root.listFiles()+"");

Outputs:

1.True
2.True
3.False
4.null

Directory is exists( I checked using isDirectory and exists() functions )
But canRead() function is returning false value, which means I dont have authority to read the directory, How to correct this?
Any solution?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of your code

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: @BhuvaneshBS  its asking you need atleast 15 reputation to upload any images.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text.

Comment: Uploaded the code